# Theorem Prover: How to optimize a backward proof search containing a "useless rule AND"

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, proof, theorem-proving, proof-system

**Quick review:**

- Inference rule = conclusion + rule + premises
- Proof tree = conclusion + rule + sub-trees
- Backward proof search: given an input goal, try to build a proof tree by applying inference rules in bottom-up way (for example, the goal is the final conclusion, after applying a rule, it will generate a list of new sub-goals on the premises)

**Problem:**
Given an input goal (e.g. `A AND B,C`), assume that we apply the rule AND firstly on `A AND B`, then get two new sub-goals, the first one is `A,C`, the second one is `B,C`.
The problem is that `A` and `B` are useless, which means we can build a complete proof tree using only `C`. However, we have two sub-goals, then we have to prove `C` two times, so it is really **inefficient**.

**Question:**
For example, we have `A AND B,C AND D,E AND F,G,H AND I`. In this case, we only need D and G to build a complete proof tree. So how to choose the right rules to apply?

This is an example code in Ocaml:

```
(* conclusion -> tree *)
let rec prove goal =                                          (* the function builds a proof tree from an input goal *)
  let rule      = get_rule goal in                            (* get the first rule *)
  let sub-goals = apply_rule goal in                          (* apply a rule *)
  let sub-trees = List.map (fun g -> prove g) sub-goals in    (* prove sub-goals recursively *)
  (goal, rule, sub-trees)                                     (* return proof tree *)
```

Comment: Do you mean how can we find the shortest (shallowest) proof tree, or how do you avoid re-doing the same proof for a subgoal that appeared twice in the proof search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the shortest (shallowest) proof, which in this case uses disjunction introduction and avoids conjunction introduction, then you can look at techniques like [iterative deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). For instance you could change your code as follows:

```
let rec prove n goal =
  if n=0 then failwith "No proof found" else
  let rule      = get_rule goal in
  let sub-goals = apply_rule goal in
  let sub-trees = List.map (fun g -> prove (n-1) g) sub-goals in
  (goal, rule, sub-trees)

let idfs maxn goal =
  let rec aux n =
    if n > maxn then None else
    try 
      Some (prove n goal)
    with Failure _ -> aux (n+1) in
  aux 1
```

If you want to avoid re-doing the proof for a sub-goal that has already appeared, then you can use some form of memoization (a narrow form of lemma speculation/application really). See for instance the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454981/memoization-in-ocaml), especially the second answer since `prove` is naturally recursive.

These suggestions do not touch the subject of how you pick the rules to apply, that is how exactly `get_rule` is coded. In practice, many options will be available and you would want to iterate through them.